# Z-table accuracy and "reverse" estimation.

Tags: normal-distribution

Say we need a value $s$ such that: 
$$P(Z\le s) = 0.995$$
Using the cumulative $Z$ table (with 3 decimal-place accuracy), I realized you can get several estimated values of $s$:

These include $$2.574, 2.575, 2.576, 2.577, 2.578, 2.579$$
Due to the limit of accuracy, all these values are correct.

My question is, is there any better way of getting a more "accurate" value or are all of these values acceptable (at the A-Level/high school level)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends both on the number of digits in the $Z$ and $\Phi(Z)$ values in your table.  The one in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table) only shows $Z$ to two places past the decimal but shows the $\Phi(Z)$ values to five places.  Looking at that table, any $Z$ between $2.55$ and $2.61$ returns a value which would round the probability to $0.995$ to three places.  The one that is closest is $2.58$.  You can interpolate the table to get more accuracy.  This table gives $P(2.57)=0.99492, P(2.58)=0.99506$.  The simplest is linear interpolation, which essentially takes these two points as exact and fits a line through them.  We find $z(0.995)=2.57+\frac {0.99500-0.99492}{0.99506-0.99492}(2.58-2.57)\approx 2.575$.  By looking at successive values in the area you can see that the function is quite linear in this region.  When I check with Alpha I find the correct value is about $2.57583$.  If the table you have only gives $\Phi(Z)$ to three places there is not much you can do besides take the middle one.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. About, linear interpolation, is it viable most of the time? Isn't normal distribution a curve?

Comment: We are taking two points on the curve and approximating the curve between the two points with a straight line.  If the curve is not a straight line it will not be exact, but it often will be good enough.  The next order term would depend on the second derivative, so if that is small or the distance between the points is small it will be a good approximation.